# Variables reset to zero after update (Uniity, C#)

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

Sorry for my bad coding I just got back into it after a while and I realize this could be a lot more optimized.

The main goal is to set all my variables and then when there is a change I want it to be announced. Here is what I have, after one update they all get set to zero.

More in-depth way: I it set at the start for the "New" vars which are used for the updates to be equal to the starting vars. After that I make it check if the "new" vars are the same as the starting vars every update and if they aren't I make it read out what the "new" vars are then have it replace the starting vars with the "new" vars. This should make it that any difference is only noticed once.

**Explanation of my code:** This took a while but I think it will work, the top part gives code its variables I'm setting this time for example but later will be more like strength and speed where they get changed around with gameplay. I then create the interger variables which will be used in the updates. When the game starts it reads me out the variables and they are all correct. I then set at the start for the "New" vars which are used for the updates to be equal to the starting vars. After that I make it check if the "new" vars are the same as the starting vars every update and if they aren't I make it read out what the "new" vars are then have it replace the starting vars with the "new" vars. This should make it that any difference is only noticed once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCharacterVarsScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //These are base character stats
    private int CharacterLife = 100; //  out of 125
    private int CharacterStamina = 100; // out of 100
    private int CharacterSight = 12; // out of 40
    private int CharacterHunger = 100; // out of 100
    private int CharacterExp = 0; // out of 100,000
    private float CharacterStrength;

    //These are the update stats
    int NewCharacterLife;
    int NewCharacterStamina;
    int NewCharacterSight;
    int NewCharacterHunger;
    int NewCharacterExp;

    float NewCharacterStrength;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        int CharacterLife = 100; //  out of 125
        int CharacterStamina = 100; // out of 100
        int CharacterSight = 12; // out of 40
        int CharacterHunger = 100; // out of 100
        int CharacterExp = 0;

        float CharacterStrength = ((CharacterHunger * .2f) + (CharacterLife * .15f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40
        float CharacterSpeed = ((CharacterHunger * .1f) + (CharacterLife * .25f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40

        Debug.Log ("Character life is " + CharacterLife);
        Debug.Log ("Character Strength is " + CharacterStrength);
        Debug.Log ("Character Stamina is " + CharacterStamina);
        Debug.Log ("Character sight is " + CharacterSight);
        Debug.Log ("Character Hunger is " + CharacterHunger);
        Debug.Log ("Character EXP is " + CharacterExp);
        Debug.Log ("Character Speed is " + CharacterSpeed);

        int NewCharacterLife = CharacterLife;
        int NewCharacterStamina = CharacterStamina;
        int NewCharacterSight = CharacterSight;
        int NewCharacterHunger = CharacterHunger;
        int NewCharacterExp = CharacterExp;

        float NewCharacterStrength = CharacterStrength;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () 
    {
        float CharacterStrength = ((CharacterHunger * .2f) + (CharacterLife * .15f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40
        float CharacterSpeed = ((CharacterHunger * .1f) + (CharacterLife * .25f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40

        if (CharacterLife != NewCharacterLife) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Character life is now " + NewCharacterLife);
            NewCharacterLife = CharacterLife;
        } 
        else if (CharacterStamina != NewCharacterStamina) 
        { 
            Debug.Log ("Character Stamina is now " + NewCharacterStamina); 
            CharacterStamina = NewCharacterStamina;
        } 
        else if (CharacterSight != NewCharacterSight) 
        { 
            Debug.Log ("Character Sight is now " + NewCharacterSight); 
            CharacterSight = NewCharacterSight;
        } 
        else if (CharacterHunger != NewCharacterHunger) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Character Hunger is now " + NewCharacterHunger); 
            CharacterHunger = NewCharacterHunger;
        }
        else if (CharacterExp != NewCharacterExp) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Character EXP is now " + NewCharacterExp);
            CharacterExp = NewCharacterExp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have member variables and local variables with exactly the same name. Was this on purpose?

Comment: Could this be playing into the issue? I'm going to research into this some as with what I said before I just got back into this after a while.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this a while after I changed it up a bit and this seems to work temporarily:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCharacterVarsScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //These are base character stats

    private int CharacterLife = 100; //  out of 125
    private int CharacterStamina = 100; // out of 100
    private int CharacterSight = 12; // out of 40
    private int CharacterHunger = 100; // out of 100
    private int CharacterExp = 0; // out of 100,000
    private float CharacterStrength;

    //These are the update stats

    int NewCharacterLife;
    int NewCharacterStamina;
    int NewCharacterSight;
    int NewCharacterHunger;
    int NewCharacterExp;

    float NewCharacterStrength;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        float CharacterStrength = ((CharacterHunger * .2f) + (CharacterLife * .15f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40

        float CharacterSpeed = ((CharacterHunger * .1f) + (CharacterLife * .25f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40

        Debug.Log ("Character life is " + CharacterLife);
        Debug.Log ("Character Strength is " + CharacterStrength);
        Debug.Log ("Character Stamina is " + CharacterStamina);
        Debug.Log ("Character sight is " + CharacterSight);
        Debug.Log ("Character Hunger is " + CharacterHunger);
        Debug.Log ("Character EXP is " + CharacterExp);
        Debug.Log ("Character Speed is " + CharacterSpeed);

        NewCharacterLife = CharacterLife;
        NewCharacterStamina = CharacterStamina;
        NewCharacterSight = CharacterSight;
        NewCharacterHunger = CharacterHunger;
        NewCharacterExp = CharacterExp;
        NewCharacterStrength = CharacterStrength;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        float CharacterStrength = ((CharacterHunger * .2f) + (CharacterLife * .15f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40

        float CharacterSpeed = ((CharacterHunger * .1f) + (CharacterLife * .25f) + (CharacterStamina * .05f)); // out of 40

        if (CharacterLife != NewCharacterLife) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Character life is now " + NewCharacterLife);
            NewCharacterLife = CharacterLife;
        } 
        else if (CharacterStamina != NewCharacterStamina) 
        { 
            Debug.Log ("Character Stamina is now " + NewCharacterStamina); 
            CharacterStamina = NewCharacterStamina;
        } 
        else if (CharacterSight != NewCharacterSight) 
        { 
            Debug.Log ("Character Sight is now " + NewCharacterSight); 
            CharacterSight = NewCharacterSight;
        } 
        else if (CharacterHunger != NewCharacterHunger) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Character Hunger is now " + NewCharacterHunger); 
            CharacterHunger = NewCharacterHunger;
        }
        else if (CharacterExp != NewCharacterExp) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Character EXP is now " + NewCharacterExp);
            CharacterExp = NewCharacterExp;
        }
    }
}
```